# Groovy - Efficiently map CSV data into object's constructor

Tags: java, grails, csv, groovy

I have an object that is composed of complex objects like this

```
class ObjectA {   
  int cool
  Object1 b   
  Object2 b 
}


class Object1 {   
  int go
  String do 
}
```

The requirement is to load CSV data from a file and assign it to an instance of the above object. I am using Grails CSV plugin and I'm able to retrieve CSV data from a file. Each row is a MAP containing values for a unique object instance. The map is in the following format:

```
cool: 1, object1go: 3, object1do: 'hello', object2hm: 'world'
```

My question is how can I efficiently pass "`object1go`" and "`object1do`" to data member (i.e. `Object1`) inside `ObjectA` class without having to do much parsing.

Comment: You can't have two properties with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how well this will work in Grails, but this works in Groovy:

```
class ObjectA {
    String name
    Object1 object1
    Object2 object2

    ObjectA(java.util.Map attrs) {
    attrs.each { key, val ->
        this.class.declaredFields.each {
            if (!it.synthetic) {
                def className = it.type.name.toLowerCase()
                def localVar = it.name
                if (key =~ /^${className}/) {
                    def realKey = key.replaceAll("^${className}", "")

                    if (!this."${localVar}") {
                        this."${localVar}" = Class.forName("${className.capitalize()}", true, this.class.classLoader).newInstance()
                    }

                    this."${localVar}"."${realKey}" = val.replaceAll("'", "")
                } else {
                    try {
                        this."${key}" = val.replaceAll("'", "")
                    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

class Object1 {
    String foo
    String bar
}

class Object2 {
    String foo
    String bar
}


def data = "name: 'dan', object1foo: 'food', object1bar: 'baz', object2foo: 'foor', object2bar: 'xanax'"
def attrs = data.split(',').inject([:]) { map, keyPair -> 
    keyPair.split(':').with { map[it[0].trim()] = it[1].trim() }
    map 
}

def a = new ObjectA(attrs)

assert a.name == 'dan'
assert a.object1 instanceof Object1
assert a.object2 instanceof Object2
assert a.object1.foo == 'food'
assert a.object2.foo == 'foor'
assert a.object1.bar == 'baz'
assert a.object2.bar == 'xanax'
```

Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: Yep, that's along the lines of the cleanups I'd thought of--+1

Answer (score 1):

(This is thrown together; it can be greatly enhanced/encapsulated.)

Since default ctors take maps, the easiest would be to create each object's required parameter map by sucking off the embedded object's name prefixes.

```
class Object1 {   
  int go
  String s
  String toString() {
    "<<${super.toString()}: go=${go}, s=${s}>>"
  }
}

class ObjectA {   
  int cool
  Object1 b   
  String toString() {
    "<<${super.toString()}: cool=${cool}, b=${b}>>"
  }
}

params = [cool: 1, object1go: 3, object1s: 'hello']

// Params for embedded object.
o1params = params.findAll { it.key.startsWith("object1") }

// Embedded object's property names (the above map minus the prefix).
tmp1 = o1params.collectEntries { k, v -> [(k[7..-1]): v] }

// "Parent" object's params.    
oaparams = params - o1params

oa = new ObjectA(oaparams + [b: new Object1(tmp1)])
println oa.toString()
```

There are quite a few ways this could be enhanced, all of them pretty easy and straight-forward. For example, I hard-coded the `"object1"` name and length; this could be wrapped up in a general-purpose method, a DSL, etc. The property names could be retrieved directly from the classes. There are a bunch of ways this could be made cleaner.

If you're able to change the map names from the CSV you might consider an intermediate step, like JSON, and just deserialize from that instead, though.

Comment: You actually don't need to expressly create instances of Object1. As long as your map has the right structure Groovy will create them for you as well.

Comment: @JustinPiper Ah, there you go then--wasn't sure, so I erred on the side of verbosity :/

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question. The easiest way I have found so far is to map the header column to encapsulated data members in the class. For example: Consider Main class has `ObjectB` (by the name roll) as a data member. Then in the CSV/XLS file you can name the header column as `roll.number`. When the file row is converted into a map during parsing, we can directly pass this map into the constructor and all values will be assigned accordingly i.e. all complex child objects will get initialized with values defined in your file.

I have implemented this technique and it works like a charm.